# NodeJS MSSQL driver cannot read property `.then` of undefined using Pools

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express

Working with the MSSQL driver in NodeJS and trying to use pools to keep the connections to the DB clean and keep from having issues where the connection doesn't close properly. Now that I'm moving from standard calls to pools, I've been getting an odd error.

My code on the Express route is as follows:

```
app.get('/records/pending/:id', (req, res) => {
    try{
        dbq.getOnePending(req.params.id).then((set) => {
            res.send(set);
        });
    }catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

which was fine for using a standard connection to the DB which looked like this:

```
dbq.getOnePending = (id) => {
    return mssql.connect(sqlConfig).then(() => {
        return new mssql.Request().query(` <<query>> `)
               .then((set) => {
                  mssql.close();
                  return set;
               }).catch((err) => {
                   console.error(err);
                   mssql.close();
               });
       });
}
```

Now, I've moved to a connection Pool model, and I can't use `.then()` in the express code. as I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

The pool version of the query looks like this:

```
  getOnePending: (id) => {
    sweepPool.request().query(`<<query>> `, (err, res) => {
      if(err){
        console.error(err);
        return err;
      }else{
        return res;
      }
    });
  },
```

How should I go about accessing the res object if I can't use `then()`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the standard interface into the connection pool, I used the fluent interface to allow for `.then()` and `.catch()`.

The standard form of the connection pool request function looks like this:

`ConnectionPool.request().query(<<query>>, callback(error, response));`

to allow for my use case where I wanted to get up and running with similar code to the standard connection, I used the functions below as a starting point.

**Example Query Function**

```
getAllPending = () => {
    return sweepPool.request().query(`<<query>>`).then((set) => {
                     console.log(set);
                     return set;
                     }).catch((err) => {
                       console.error(err);
                       return err;
                     });
}
```

**Call to Query Function**

```
app.get('/records/pending', (req, res) => {
      try{
          dbq.getAllPending().then((set) => {
               res.send(set);
          });
         }catch(err){
           console.error(err);
           res.send(err);
         }
});
```

Of Course, this doesn't actually handle the error, but is a nice starting point.